# Chrome extension query: How to update context menu from content script in time for it to be included in the context menu?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that will add DOM information to the context menu (as a child item) when an element is right clicked.  The code I have so far does put the information I want into the context menu, and console log shows the child items being added at the right point (and both are free of errors), but not in time for it to be included in the initial rendered context menu.

The ultimate effect being, I have to right click the element *twice* to see the context menu child items created by the *first* click.

The (slightly simplified) code I have currently is below:

content script:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
    if(event.button == 2) { 
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(event.target.nodeName);
    }
}, true);
```

background:

```
var parent = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Node", "contexts":["all"]});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(nodename, sender, sendResponse) {
      chrome.contextMenus.create(
        {"title": nodename, "parentId": parent});
  });
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My extension",
  "description": "This is an example extension.",
  "version": "0.1",

  "permissions": ["contextMenus", "clipboardWrite"],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "*://*/*"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way I can get the information added to the context menu in time for it to be included?

Answer (score 0):

Define doSomething. Then it will work.

As it is, it's creating an error in the background context (on the extension page, click on the "Inspect views: background page" to view the console for the background.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking a look.  The doSomething _is_ defined (though doesn't actually do much at the moment).  I've updated the question to reflect that, thanks.

Comment: Thanks very much for that.  It's not working for me unfortunately but I'll try creating a stripped down version, and building up again from there.

Comment: Very strange. I've created a new minimal repro with the code: https://pastebin.com/MGCwRvgC

and it looks like the behaviour I'm seeing is
 - It takes two clicks for the first clicked item to appear in the context menu
 - If I right click an A tag it adds that value to the context menu _but_ you can't see it until you click on a different kind of node (eg DIV), and _then_ it appears.

Comment: Yes that right - but I still see the original issue of - on a fresh load of the extension, right clicking a div will show the parent 'Node' item but not the child item (though log will show that it was added as a child item) - but on a second right click the div item from the first click is visible (as well as another log message saying a second was added).  Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: For me, a div span or p shows right away as it should, i.e. as soon as you let go of the mouse, the child is on the menu

Comment: Well, that's infuriating!  This is what I see https://i.imgur.com/58R3yLN.gif.  I'll try & get someone else to try it out.  Thanks very much for all your help!